# mpv player - how to activate teletext subtitles?

Tags: mpv

Does anyone know how to configure mpv.conf for mpv player in order to activate teletext subtitles?
According to manual *--teletext-page=<1-999>* should do what I need but it doesn't.

Any other suggestion, like using a lua script?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is about using/configuring the mpv, while the mpv tag you used is for people who are using it programmatically. Did you try these? https://mpv.io/community/

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag. Thank you for your comment.